# GKE: Finding your cluster's release channel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud

I can't seem to find my GKE cluster's release channel.

According to the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/release-channels#finding_your_clusters_channel), I should run

```
gcloud beta container clusters describe cluster-name \
  --zone compute-zone --format="value(releaseChannel.channel)"
```

But when I run it, there doesn't appear to be a releaseChannel field. I also can't find it in the web console. Is there some other way to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Your GKE Kubernetes cluster has an option to be created with `Master version` of:

- `Release channel`:

  - `Rapid`
  - `Regular`
  - `Stable`
- `Static version`:

**You will not get your `Release channel` information when cluster was created with `Static version`.**

Example:
I created 2 GKE clusters:

- *gke-release-channel* with option of `Release channel: Stable`
- *gke-static-version* with `Static version: 1.14.10-gke.24`

---

Checking the release channel with *gke-release-channel* with below command:

```sh
$ gcloud beta container clusters describe gke-release-channel --zone europe-west3-c --format="value(releaseChannel.channel)"
```

**Will output: `STABLE`**

Checking the release channel with *gke-static-version* with below command:

```
$ gcloud beta container clusters describe gke-static-version --zone europe-west3-c --format="value(releaseChannel.channel)"
```

**The output will be empty**

---

When creating a cluster please take a specific look on:

[image: Master version]

If you created your cluster with `Release channel` you can check it by going into it's cluster details. It should be on the top:

[image: Release channel]

Comment: I guess that means I have a static version then. But it still seems as if my GKE version is getting automatically upgraded periodically. Is that expected? Maybe as older versions get deprecated?

Comment: Looking at documentation it seems like it is expected. `When you create a new cluster or node pool with Google Cloud Console or the gcloud command, node auto-upgrade is enabled by default`. [Cloud.google.com: Node auto-upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-auto-upgrades). If you go to your node-pool you can see that auto-upgrade is enabled.

Comment: I see. I assumed that just meant the node pool is auto-upgraded when the masters are upgraded, but the masters wouldn't be upgraded automatically.

Comment: Just to add that "Static version" is sometimes called "None" within GKE console.